# Change the scale-policy of OpenGL ES in Android?

Tags: android, libgdx

I currently develop a game for Android in OpenGL ES 1.0, use libgdx library. I target the 720x480 screen size.

For example, I design only one arts pack for 720x480. And what will happen in Android phones with screen-size smaller or bigger than it, 480x320 for instance? Could you please tell me how to change the scale-policy of OpenGL ES in Android? Or in libgdx specially?

Is there anything like "Resample Image" like photoshop?(Nearest Neighbor, Bilinear, Bicubic etc..) for libgdx?

**Edit**: I found some tutorials about texture filter in OpenGL, test it with Linear and Nearest. Linear is good for scaling but slow down the game, and Nearest is on the contrary. What should I do to get a balance between those?

Answer (score 2):

You can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11136438/923847).
What you should do is create all your assets in a few different sizes. And then load the appropriate size depending on the device. See my link for how libgdx can help with all that.